# Codemirror vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use the CodeMirror plugin. But my options are not working, does anyone know what it is?

Template code:

```
<div>
<Codemirror v-model="code" options="{ mode: 'javascript', lineNumbers: false}" :extensions="extensions" />
</div>
```

Script:

```
import { Codemirror } from 'vue-codemirror'
import { javascript } from "@codemirror/lang-javascript";
import { oneDark } from "@codemirror/theme-one-dark";

export default {
components: {
  Codemirror
},
data() {
   return {
     extensions: [javascript(), oneDark],
     code: 'text\nsadasd\nsadjasopdjops\ndaksdas',
   }
 },
}
```

My `lineNumbers: false` doesnt work.

Thanks

.....................................................

Comment: add `:` to the front of `options` else you're passing a string, just like you have done with `:extensions`